# Join usage in Update SubQuery in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update table's one column with SubQuery.
I have two tables.
In first one, i keep number of products named 'products'.
I use second table as basket named 'basket'.
First, user add products to basket. After payment, i want to update stock ('products' table 'stock' column).
If we name stock as 'stock' and users bought products numbers b_stock, formul will be as stock -= b_stock. stock will be read from products.stock and b_stock will be read basket.products.
Sure i will need customer parameter as @cus.
Thanks for you reply.

Comment: I do not see any question here? :)
Maybe You can clarify exactly what problem You are facing, and provide some code for us to work on?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Here is my code;

update products set products.stock -= (select s.b_stock from basket as s where s.customer = (select id from customers where customer = @cus) and s.product = products.id) where (select product from basket where customer= @cus) = (select id from products)

Comment: It would help if you formatted your query as an edit to your question, instead of a comment that is hard to read.   As for your code, I think your outer UPDATE query needs a FROM clause, so that it can correlate to the sub-queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what You seek is [EXIST](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188336%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) clause.

I can not test it, and I am not sure if I get correctly Your keys on the tables. Below some code that **might** help You.

```
update 
    products p
set 
p.stock = 
(
    select 
        p.stock - b.b_stock 
    from 
        basket as b
    JOIN customers c ON (b.customer = c.id) 
    where 
        c.customer = @cus
    and b.product = p.id
) 
where EXIST
(
    select 
        1
    from 
        basket b1
    JOIN customers c1 ON (b1.customer = c1.id) 
    where 
    c1.customer = @cus
    AND p.id = b1.product
)
```